# How to pass a web service to a MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, controller, wsdl

I wondered if you can help with my query. I am trying to use an WSDL web service and call it into a MVC controller and returning it as a view but it does not work any ideas?

I have added it as a service in my project however when I attempt to use it within a controller and return a view I get error.

Here are the steps, codes and issues:

1. FYI, I am using the following public WSDL (http://w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx) to test my code
2. A proxy class was generated using the WSDL above
3. I created an instance of the proxy class and called a method for testing
4. Passed that object as parameter to View
5. Generated a view for the method
   a.    Tried to pass the proxy class as model reference but it does not work as it throws an error message
   b.    It passes the value but still throw an error

```
using Temp.Models;
namespace Temp.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public TempConvertSoapClient client = new TempConvertSoapClient("TempConvertSoap");
       public ActionResult Index() {
           string result = client.CelsiusToFahrenheit("14");
           return View(result);
       }
       public ActionResult Other() {
           ProxyTest test = new ProxyTest();
           var result = test.service.CelsiusToFahrenheit("23");
           return View(result);
       }
     }
 }
```

> Code from the View is below the view '57.2' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Home/57.2.aspx ~/Views/Home/57.2.ascx ~/Views/Shared/57.2.aspx ~/Views/Shared/57.2.ascx

Are you able to advise what might be the issue?

P. S. I am using Visual Studio and C#

Comment: You should add information to your question using the [edit] button provided.

Comment: @Brian Many thanks. Do you have a view as to why my code isn't working ?  i suspect this is because it is expecting a model but then not sure how to create an instance of the proxy in the model ?!

Comment: I am only acting as a question reviewer. Badly constructed questions, like yours, go through a community resourced review process so they can be rendered more tractable to those who may be able to answer. The best you can do to get an answer is to review more of the guidance given in [help], such as [ask]. Your goal should be to include as all the information an expert would need so they answer the minute they see your question. I am not the expert you seek in this topic, although I am in other topics.

Comment: No worries, thanks a bunch!